# Save content of divs on different positions

Tags: jquery, asp.net, sql, drag-and-drop, draggable

I have on the left some names(divs) and on the right 3 squares which are divs (nr1, nr2, nr3).
I can drag the three names on the right squares and make a top 3. All this is done with jquery.

How can i save in an sql database with asp.net the positions and names which were dragged on the squares.

Answer (score 0):

I think when you click the save button get the child divs inside the container div. Then save it like a parent-child relationship.Get the position (left and top) of the chid div (relative position to parent) and save that too

the table records may look like

**ChildId**      **ParentId**       **ChildLeftPosition**    **ChildTopPosition**

--------  --------    ----------------- ------------------

```
nr1        Parent1        25                 12
nr2        Parent1        65                 48
nr3        Parent1        210                97
```

and when u render back, read these values and position it

Answer (score 0):

```
function SaveNames()
{
    var NameForN1 = [];
    var NameForN2 = [];
    var NameForN3 = [];

    $('#nr1').children().each(function()
    {
         NameForN1.push($(this).html());
    });
    //TODO: Do the same for nr2 and nr3
    $.post('yoururl',{Names:[NameForN1,NameForN2,NameForN3]},callback);
}
```

That's for the client Side, for the server side now

```
protected void SaveItems()
{
    Dictionnary<string,object> myNames;
    System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer jvs = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
    myNames = jvs.Deserialize<Dictionnary<string,object>>(Request["Names"]);
    //TODO Now you only have to save it to the database.
}
```

The myNames["Names"] should be (if I'm right) an array of array of strings.
If that does'nt work on the server side if you're using asp.net 4.0 I suggest you read this article about some cool tools for Json deserialization : [Hanselman blog's](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NuGetPackageOfTheWeek4DeserializingJSONWithJsonNET.aspx)